# firrtl_interpreter.InterpreterException: error: ConcreteSInt(303, 9) bad width 9 needs 10

Tags: chisel

I've got a module that generates the following FIRRTL

```
module Deep_1 : 
    input clock : Clock
    input reset : UInt<1>
    output io : {in : {flip data : SInt<8>[4]}, constIn : {flip data : SInt<8>[4]}, ...}
    ...
    ... (elided)
    ...
    wire inputData : SInt<8>[4] @[Deep.scala 32:23]
    wire constInputData : SInt<8>[4] @[Deep.scala 33:28]
    reg outputData : SInt<8>[4], clock @[Deep.scala 34:23]
    inputData[2] <= io.in.data[2] @[Deep.scala 37:18]
    constInputData[2] <= io.constIn.data[2] @[Deep.scala 38:23]
    node _T_209 = add(inputData[2], constInputData[2]) @[package.scala 32:44]
    node _T_210 = tail(_T_209, 1) @[package.scala 32:44]
    node _T_211 = asSInt(_T_210) @[package.scala 32:44]
    outputData[2] <= _T_211 @[Deep.scala 39:19]
    ...
    ... (elided)
    ...
```

but when I try to run my tests through the firrtl interpreter I get

```
Exception during evaluation: error: ConcreteSInt(303, 9) bad width 9 needs 10  @[package.scala 32:44:@82.4]
Expression Evaluation stack
   0 dut.outputData_2:Reg -> dut._T_211
   1 dut._T_211:Node -> asSInt(dut._T_210)
   2 dut._T_210:Node -> tail(dut._T_209, 1)
   3 dut._T_209:Node -> add(dut.inputData_2, dut.constInputData_2)
```

If I understand this correctly, it is saying that the width of `outputData[2]` is 9 but 10 is needed. However, from what I can see, the width of both `outputData[2]` and `_T_211` should be 8, the first by definition and the second as a result of the `add()` and `tail()` operations applied.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you also tried `treadle` or emitting the Verilog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How current is your software? I cannot reproduce the problem with current versions of the interpreter. I used the following firrtl test in the gist [Attempt to reproduce firrtl-interpreter width error](https://gist.github.com/chick/2e30326f1085b28b7ac5afef09c52134) where I un-elided.  As @Kamyar said, can you try using the Treadle backend. It is more modern and better supported at this point than is the interpreter.

Comment: I switched to the treadle backend by specifying `Driver(..., "treadle")` and the problem went away. Thank you!